# Debian - Solr doesn't start and log file is getting deleted

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I just downloaded the newest version of Solr from http://www.eu.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/5.3.1/solr-5.3.1.tgz

Then I unpacked it with `tar zxvf solr-5.3.1.tgz` moved into the /bin/ directory with cd /solr-5.3.1/bin to start the binary with

```
./solr start
```

According to tutorials and readme more is not needed for a first trial run.

> Waiting up to 30 seconds to see Solr running on port 8983
>
> [-]  Still not seeing Solr listening on 8983 after 30 seconds!
>
> tail: „/var/solr/logs/solr.log“ cannot be opened for reading

So I created the directory and the solr.log file and restarted it with

`./solr start`

The log file is automatically deleted by solr and the error is the same, that the log file is not readable. This is a funny loop. How can I find a way to read the log file to understand why solr is not starting?

java -version

> java version "1.6.0_36"
>
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.8) (6b36-1.13.8-1~deb7u1)
>
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the log file is being deleted - it's probably just never created. Solr and Lucene 5.3 require Java 7, so if the Java6 VM is the JVM used for starting Solr - it's going to fail.

You can use `./solr start -f` to get Solr to run in the foreground to  catch any errors, but if the logging sub system never starts, it might not do much good.

Comment: Thank you, I updated the Java version to 1.8 and all is running now.