# Solr 5.3 on Debian Wheezy cannot open log file

Tags: solr, debian

I am trying to install Solr 5.3.1 on a server that runs Debian Wheezy 7.9

I ran the install script `install_solr_service.sh` but can't start the solr server.

When using `solr start`it waits the 30 seconds and then prints:

```
Still not seeing Solr listening on 8983 after 30 seconds!
tail: cannot open `/opt/solr/server/logs/solr.log' for reading: No such file or directory
```

When I create the missing log file, the first thing `solr start` does is to delete it.

I've tried creating the file with the same permissions and owner/group as the rest of the solr installation, no success.
I've tried starting slr on both ports `8080` and `8983`, no success.

Any Idea?

Comment: Two questions pop up in my mind: Is port 8983 free and good for usage? Does the folder `/opt/solr/server/logs/` exist and can the user Solr is running with access it?

Comment: @cheffe the port should be free. I know for sure that 8080 is free since I killed the tomcat server that was running on it. The logs folder exists and has Solr as owner... I won't be able to answer more precisely until next Monday though. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Which version of java are you using? Wheezy comes with java 6 by default, bur solr needs java 7. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33278126/debian-solr-doesnt-start-and-log-file-is-getting-deleted

Comment: @ClemensKlein-Robbenhaar Thank you for this link! I did not find that question even though I did search a lot before posting here... I'll let you know if this was the issue so that you can post as an answer if yes. What is the procedure for duplicate questions?

Comment: @BarthyBonhomme it is not yet clear if this is the same problem as in the linked answer. If it is, let us know, and the moderators will mark it as duplicate. (I do not know which step the author of a question can take to mark a question as duplicate.)

Comment: @ClemensKlein-Robbenhaar updating java solved my problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Clemens mentioned in comments, the solution was to simply update java.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check the following solr log file: /server/logs/solr-***port***-console.log
2. If there's an error likes 'Cannot allocate memory',

   2.1 You should start solr with more memory OR

   2.2 You should clean up some memory on solr machine OR

   2.3 You should start you virtual machine with more memory ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it may be useful for others. My Problem has been solved though, I'll post the answer and mark it as accepted.