# Solr doesn't start automatically

Tags: solr

```
 solr-5.4.0 version
```

My Java version

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.3) (7u91-2.6.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.91-b01, mixed mode)
```

I did all steps finally am getting this error

```
sudo service solr status
```

Found 1 Solr nodes:

```
Solr process 6003 from /var/solr/solr-8983.pid not found.
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Have you tried deleting that pid file? I would make sure that Solr is stopped, delete that pid, and then attempt to start it again.

Comment: How to delete the pid?

Comment: Delete any .pid files in `/var/solr/`.

Comment: root@dindudu:/var/solr# ls
data  log4j.properties  logs  solr-8983.pid
root@dindudu:/var/solr# rm solr-8983.pid

Comment: root@dindudu:/var/solr# sudo service solr start
Waiting up to 30 seconds to see Solr running on port 8983 [/]  Still not seeing Solr listening on 8983 after 30 seconds!
tail: cannot open ‘/var/solr/logs/solr.log’ for reading: No such file or directory

Comment: I created log file like this. touch solr.log after create i can see the file under the log folder while start the solr log file is removed

Comment: Hmm, OK. Could you edit your question to include a link to the steps you took? I want to see if I can reproduce this.

Comment: ohh Thanks.I gothru this url to install solr https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-solr-5-2-1-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Ah, OK. I think I may have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

That [Digital Ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-solr-5-2-1-on-ubuntu-14-04) recommends Java 8 with Solr 5 and provides installation instructions using a PPA. I also found [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33278711/5721508) where switching to Java 8 was the resolution.

I created a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 VM using Vagrant and VirtualBox with these commands...

```
vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64
vagrant up
```

Then I followed the tutorial with Solr 5.4.0, and got the same error you did. However, my Solr logs were not deleted, so I was able to find this...

```
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 402653184 bytes for committing reserved memory.
```

My Vagrant VM had 512 MB of RAM so I doubled that to 1 GB which is recommended in the tutorial, did a `vagrant reload`, and Solr started working. Here is my minimal Vagrantfile...

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = "1024"
  end
end
```

I'm using VirtualBox 5.0.10 and Vagrant 1.8.1. I hope this works for you.

**UPDATE:** I just went through the tutorial again with a 32-bit Ubuntu 14.04 VM (`ubuntu/trusty32` in Vagrantfile) and that also worked. So if you're on a 32-bit host or the 64-bit VM doesn't work for you, the 32-bit VM should work.

Comment: OK Thank You i will try solr 5.3

Comment: solor 5.3.0 sudo service solr start
Waiting up to 30 seconds to see Solr running on port 8983 [/]  Still not seeing Solr listening on 8983 after 30 seconds!
tail: cannot open ‘/var/solr/logs/solr.log’ for reading: No such file or directory

Comment: http://<ipaddress>:8080/solr/admin this url i can see solr is running but version is  Solr Specification Version: 3.6.2.2013.12.15.17.23.54
 Solr Implementation Version: 3.6.2 debian - buildd - 2013-12-15 17:23:54
 Lucene Specification Version: 3.6.2

Comment: The important thing is to upgrade to Java 8. That should work fine with Solr 5.4.

Comment: java -version
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode) This is java 8

Comment: OK, so you've tried Java 8 with Solr 5.4? I think at this point you may want to delete the init script at `/etc/init.d/solr` and try re-running the Solr install script now that Java 8 is the default version.

Comment: I just created a new Ubuntu 14.04 Vagrant box, followed the steps in the Digital Ocean tutorial, and got the same error you did with Java 8 and Solr 5.4.0. At least it's reproducible. I'll see about fixing it.

Comment: ohh Nice . what is the solution ?

Comment: It's in the answer above. I updated it earlier today.

Comment: I want to create Vagrant box ?

Comment: I just wanted to verify that the tutorial will work and Vagrant was an easy way to set up a fresh Ubuntu server for testing. The fix for me was to increase the RAM from 512 MB to 1 GB. If you just want to get the tutorial working, then the Vagrant option should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I will throw my answer in here just in case someone else spends another hour like I did.

Solr version 6.1.0 + Java 1.7 same error.

I had to upgrade to 1.8. How did I know that was the problem?

```
:/var/solr/logs# cat solr-8983-console.log 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/jetty/start/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
    at ....
```

The 52 version means you need Java 1.8.
Upgrade Ubuntu using

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java 
$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Credit to this [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/716786/solr-doesnt-start-and-log-file-is-getting-deleted#comment1092937_735612).