# solr5.4 installation using brew does not start as it cannot find the solr.log file

Tags: solr, osx-elcapitan

i have tried installing solr on osx El capitan using brew

```
brew install solr
```

it completed the installation successfully and then when i tried to start the solr instance it gave the following error

```
Rohans-Mac-mini:Documents iRoan$ solr start
Waiting up to 30 seconds to see Solr running on port 8983 [\]  Still not seeing Solr listening on 8983 after 30 seconds!
tail: /usr/local/Cellar/solr/5.4.1/server/logs/solr.log: No such file or directory
```

i tried creating an empty solr.log file in the said location but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your Java version is probably too old. I basically asked the same question a couple of months ago.

[Debian - Solr doesn't start and log file is getting deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33278126/debian-solr-doesnt-start-and-log-file-is-getting-deleted)

Comment: it was using wrong java version on console
java version "1.6.0_65"
http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u73-b02/jdk-8u73-macosx-x64.dmg?AuthParam=1456134286_d24c2f2c578eff99da2510f942b3d3bb
so downloaded jdk from above link and installed so now java got updated
java version "1.8.0_73"